# UISegmentedControl wrong dividerImage

Tags: ios, uiview, uiimage, uisegmentedcontrol

I am custumizing all segmented controls in my app with the following code.Initially I set the selected segment to index 2.

Everything works perfect in IOS 6.While I was testing the app on IOS5, I realised that the initial setting of segmented control had a bug.The separation image between selected and unselected state is not set right.Due to that it looks like this.

If i change the selected segments by tapping the segmentedcontrol behaves normal.It is very weird.What elsse shall i do to prevent this strange behaviour?

[image: Initial setting]

```
     UISegmentedControl *localSegmentedControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] init];

     if ([localSegmentedControl respondsToSelector:@selector(setBackgroundImage:forState:barMetrics:)]) {

    UIImage *segmentUnselectedSelectedDivider       = [UIImage imageNamed:@"segmentedControlSeperatorNS.png"];
    UIImage *segmentSelectedUnselectedDivider       = [UIImage imageNamed:@"segmentedControlSeperatorSN.png"];
    UIImage *segmentUnselectedUnselectedDivider     = [UIImage imageNamed:@"segmentedControlSeperatorNN.png"];

    UIImage *segmentUnselected = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"barButtonPlain.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:7 topCapHeight:0];
    UIImage *segmentSelected = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"doneButton.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:7 topCapHeight:0];


    [[UISegmentedControl appearance] setBackgroundImage:segmentUnselected
                                               forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    [[UISegmentedControl appearance] setBackgroundImage:segmentSelected
                                               forState:UIControlStateSelected barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];


    [[UISegmentedControl appearance] setDividerImage:segmentUnselectedUnselectedDivider
                                 forLeftSegmentState:UIControlStateNormal
                                   rightSegmentState:UIControlStateNormal
                                          barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

    [[UISegmentedControl appearance] setDividerImage:segmentSelectedUnselectedDivider
                                 forLeftSegmentState:UIControlStateSelected
                                   rightSegmentState:UIControlStateNormal
                                          barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

    [[UISegmentedControl appearance] setDividerImage:segmentUnselectedSelectedDivider
                                 forLeftSegmentState:UIControlStateNormal
                                   rightSegmentState:UIControlStateSelected
                                          barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];


}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Weird behavior with UISegmentedControl and UIAppearance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11183519/weird-behavior-with-uisegmentedcontrol-and-uiappearance) - my answer there has a working workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying all relevant approached explained in [Customizing UISegmentedControl in iOS 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9114186/customizing-uisegmentedcontrol-in-ios-5)

i figured out that the problem is related with the width of the separation line.The tutorial about segmented control customisation in http://www.raywenderlich.com/4344/user-interface-customization-in-ios-5 assumes that the separation images are wider than 2px (in Retina).
I made them exactly 2px wide and the problem is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is a known bug. 
It is the same here with a workaround, may work for you.

[Customizing UISegmentedControl in iOS 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9114186/customizing-uisegmentedcontrol-in-ios-5)

Answer (score 0):

When i use segment control I was very tired the same problem. I solved that code

```
  UIImage *segmentSelected =
[[UIImage imageNamed:@"ikisiSecildiKirmizi.png"]
 resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 15, 5, 15)];
UIImage *segmentUnselected =
[[UIImage imageNamed:@"ikisiSecilmediGri.png"]
 resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 15, 5, 15)];
UIImage *segmentSelectedUnselected =
[[UIImage imageNamed:@"solSecili.png"]resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 15, 5, 15)];
UIImage *segUnselectedSelected =
[[UIImage imageNamed:@"sagSecili.png"]resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 15, 5, 15)];

UIImage *segmentUnselectedUnselected =
[[UIImage imageNamed:@"ikisideSecilmemis.png"]resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 15, 5, 15)];

[fiyatSaat setBackgroundImage:segmentUnselected
                     forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[fiyatSaat setBackgroundImage:segmentSelected
                     forState:UIControlStateSelected barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

[fiyatSaat setDividerImage:segmentUnselectedUnselected
       forLeftSegmentState:UIControlStateNormal
         rightSegmentState:UIControlStateNormal
                barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

[fiyatSaat setDividerImage:segmentSelectedUnselected
       forLeftSegmentState:UIControlStateSelected
         rightSegmentState:UIControlStateNormal
                barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

[fiyatSaat setDividerImage:segUnselectedSelected
       forLeftSegmentState:UIControlStateNormal
         rightSegmentState:UIControlStateSelected
                barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

NSDictionary *attributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[UIColor blackColor]
                                                       forKey:UITextAttributeTextColor];
[fiyatSaat setTitleTextAttributes:attributes
                         forState:UIControlStateNormal];
NSDictionary *attributes2 = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[UIColor whiteColor]
                                                       forKey:UITextAttributeTextColor];
[fiyatSaat setTitleTextAttributes:attributes2
                         forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
```

Comment: what is size of your segment backgroudns and seperation lines ?

Comment: segment backgrounds and seperation lines are same size 33x34 for retina display